# Not displaying tiles on Android offline maps app using osmdroid with MBTiles file

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid, mbtiles

I need to develop an Android app that needs to display maps but has to work offline all of the time, also the maps correspond to a small city, after browsing a bit I stumbled upon `osmdroid`, and this along with the usage of a small `.mbtiles` file seemed ideal, in fact i used [this fine post](http://www.sieswerda.net/2012/08/13/integrating-osmdroid-part-2/) to help me out.

After running the sample app, the `MapView` gets displayed but no tile does, only default grey tiles. The only thing resembling an error i can find is the following snippet on the debugger:

```
09-26 16:55:53.931      353-353/com.example.myfirstapp2        I/dalvikvm: Could not find method org.osmdroid.views.MapView.getScaleX, referenced from method org.osmdroid.views.overlay.SafeDrawOverlay.draw
09-26 16:55:53.931      353-353/com.example.myfirstapp2        W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1476: Lorg/osmdroid/views/MapView;.getScaleX ()F
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the same errors, the fact is that same code was showing maps and without any code change it just stopped working. I started to think it has something to do with the server side.

Comment: Maybe you can post some code, and tell us what you are trying to do? You are using our own map, provided as a sqlite db as an asset?